# How to check city with ip address

Tags: laravel, ip, city

I am working on a real estate site. I need to show properties of a specific city only on the home page. How can I check the ip of the visitor and check the city from where he is visiting ?

Comment: Most of the time you can't. ISPs don't generally associate specific IPs with specific cities and usually have a region-wide or country wide pool. You should be using the [geolocation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

Answer (score 1):

You can get user ip with:

```
$request->ip()
```

Then you need to send request to api that give you a location of an ip, some of these services are:

1. https://ip-api.com
2. https://ipstack.com
3. https://ipapi.co

Answer (score 1):

you can use :
request()->ip();

or

you can also use
\Request::ip();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. Will try these options.